# ¿Para que sirve el from y el import?

Tags: python

No encuentro un significado que me sea útil para conocer cuando utilizarlo
Me gustaría que me ayudaseis ,ya que lo necesito para una asignatura de la universidad.
En resumen: ¿Me podríais explicar como y cuando usar  el from y el import?

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Con `import` lo que hacemos es importar módulos de la biblioteca.

Te lo explico con un ejemplo simple y práctico.

Si nosotros quisieramos generar números aleatorios, tenemos dos opciones, o nos inventamos un algoritmo que los genere o empleamos uno ya existente.

¿Que es más cómodo?  - Emplear el existente.

¿Como lo traemos? - Mediante el `import`.

En este caso hariamos:

```
import random

print(random.randrange(10))
```

Pero esto puede ir más allá, si simplemente queremos una única función del módulo, podemos traer simplemente eso.

¿Cómo lo hacemos? - Mediante `import` y `from`.

Por ejemplo queremos generar aleatorios pero que sea concretamente enteros.

```
from random import randint

print(randint(10, 20))
```

Aquí te dejo muchos diferentes módulos que existen de la biblioteca estándar [Link](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/stdlib.html)